# Any software for helping hand place components by listing 'by group'? i.e. all 10k resistors so they can be placed at one time

Tags: pcb-assembly

Sorry for the convoluted title but what software do people use when placing physical components on PCB's?
Looking for something to highlight all 10k resistors or 1nF capacitors as examples to speed picking and placing by hand.

Impossible to Google as all answers point to design software. I'm using KiCad for the design.

Comment: The HTML bom plugin for kicad does this while highlighting the position of all same values components: https://github.com/openscopeproject/InteractiveHtmlBom

Comment: That work's perfectly for what I need. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I like the "Interactive BOM" plugin for KiCAD and other tools:

https://github.com/openscopeproject/InteractiveHtmlBom

A demo is here:

https://openscopeproject.org/InteractiveHtmlBomDemo/

It allows you to create an HTML view of your board layout that highlights similar groups of components.  It is present in the KiCAD plugin library, and can also be used with other tools such as Eagle.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve used Visual place, it’s free now, or was when I last used it.  You can import bom and order it how you want.

https://www.compuphase.com/visualplace/visualplace_en.htm

Now I use a cp45 to do this..